# On API Call, I want to display the data in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On API Call, I need to display the data in table in respective fields.
I used Fetch method to display the data and right now I am getting only one field.
So I need to display all the field in the table.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from "axios";

     class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                 data:[]                               
                 }
                }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => this.setState({data:user}))
    }         
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                   {this.state.data.map(use =>(
            <h1 key={use.id} > {use.fname} </h1>
                   ))}

                     <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-8"><table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Tel</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
                    </div>

                    </div> 

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: What kind of data are you getting back? Also, you are printing data separately from the table, above it.

Comment: Json Data and Just I am printing the data separately to check whether the data is coming or not?? I actually I need the data in the table with respective Fields..
Can You help me in this... Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. Please check the syntax of the code before you run project

```
  render() {
            return (
                <div>
                     <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-8"><table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Tel</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.state.data.map(use => (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{use.fname}</td>
                                    <td>{use.lname}</td>
                                    <td>{use.tel}</td>
                                    <td>{use.add}</td>
                                    <td>{use.city}</td>
                                    <td>{use.state}</td>
                                    <td>{use.zip}</td>
                                    <td><button>edit</button></td>
                                    <td><button>delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>

                    </div> 

                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```